# TROUBLING with the "DROP_NA" Function

Tags: r

I have a problem with `drop_na()` function. I wanted to clean the dataset and erase the "NA" values, but when I entered the code, all datas are disseapperad. I do not understand why it happens.
You can see clearly what my codes are in this picture:

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
WDI_GNI<read_csv("C:/Users/sudes/Downloads/P_Data_Extract_From_World_Development_Indicators/a7b778c6-9827-4c45-91b7-8f497087ca17_Data.csv")WDI_GNI <- WDI_GNI %>%
  mutate(across(contains("[YR"),~na_if(.x, ".."))) %>%
  mutate(across(contains("[YR"), as.numeric))
WDI_GNI <- drop_na(WDI_GNI)
```

Comment: Don't make us retype your code from an image.  Post as plain text.

Comment: How are we supposed to help without seeing what your data looks like?

Comment: Welcome to SO, sssude! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages); sample representative data using `dput(head(x))`, `data.frame(..)`, `read.table(..)`, or similar; and often actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: You are telling `drop_na` to remove every row where there is at least one `NA`. For example, in `drop_na(data.frame(x=c(1,NA), y=c(NA,2)))` it will return nothing because every row has at least one `NA` in it. If there is a column where you know there are `NA`s and you don't want rows removed because of that, then you can specify them, as in `drop_na(data.frame(x=c(1,NA), y=c(NA,2)), y)` (or `drop_na(.., -y)`, depending on your needed logic). We can do nothing more than this, I think, without sample data, I hope either my comments here help or that you can post sample data. Good luck!